# 'expression is of wrong type' error while calculating difference between two dates in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to calculate difference between two dates and display the difference as days in the output. But I keep getting this error in Oracle Live sql:

```
ORA-06550: line 11, column 12:
PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
```

Here is the code:

```
create table borrower(
    roll_no number,
    date_of_issue date,
    name_of_book varchar(20),
    status varchar(10)
);

insert into borrower values(1,to_date('02-JAN-2022'),'dbms','issued');
insert into borrower values(2,to_date('10-JAN-2022'),'cns','issued');
insert into borrower values(3,to_date('17-JAN-2022'),'spos','issued');
insert into borrower values(4,to_date('26-JAN-2022'),'toc','issued');

create table fine(
    roll_no number,
    current_date date,
    amount number
);

insert into fine values(1,to_date('14-FEB-2022'),null);
insert into fine values(2,to_date('14-FEB-2022'),null);
insert into fine values(3,to_date('14-FEB-2022'),null);
insert into fine values(4,to_date('14-FEB-2022'),null);

DECLARE
    roll_counter number:=1;
    initial_date date;
    final_date date;
    date_calc date;

BEGIN
    loop
        select date_of_issue into initial_date from borrower where roll_no=roll_counter;
        select current_date into final_date from fine where  roll_no=roll_counter;
        date_calc:=final_date-initial_date;
        dbms_output.put_line(date_calc);
        roll_counter:=roll_counter+1;
        exit when roll_counter>4;
    end loop;
END;
/

drop table borrower;
drop table fine;
```

Can someone help me sort out this error. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 11 is this:

```
date_calc:=final_date-initial_date;
```

All three expressions in this formulas are declared as data type `date`.

Now do you see the problem? If you don't, think about this: what ***`date`*** is `to_date('17-JAN-2022')` ***minus*** `to_date('11-DEC-2021')`?

Look again at your problem description:

> display the difference as days in the output.

What does that mean? Difference *as days*? What data type should that be?

Comment: I didn't get what you are stating. I want to obtain the number of days between initial date and final date. For that we would need to subtract two of them, right?

Comment: @tdcoder - Right, but what is the data type of the result? Let's say it is 18 (days). You are assigning this to `date_calc`, which you declared as `date` data type. What "date" is the number 18? Find the error which you must fix in the `DECLARE` section of your code.

Comment: Ok now I get it